# Magento Product's url_key get being overwritten

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I maintain a large catalog of products in a Magento store, mostly through magento's API calls.

When I add products to the store I add them with a url_key like `manufacturer-sku` which means the product is reachable at `www.domain.com/manufacturer-sku.html`.  However, after some time the products end up changing their url_key to be the product's name, which means the product resides at `www.domain.com/sku-some-words-that-describe-the-product.html`

Why does this keep happening? And how can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best you can do, is to provide both url_key and url_path. We had the same problem. It happens if you not fully load a product and then save it. Magento thinks you haven't provided an url_key and it will generate some one for you.

To disable this feature be sure to load a product fully and/or provide always an url_key.

Second thing you can do, is to put a hidden switch while saving a product:

```
$product->setData('save_rewrites_history');
```

This will create an 301 for your old url_key and you will not loose them at all.